# How to make slider current position when it stopped

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I'm making timer application and I have countdown slider.
I want to get current position of slider when I pause it.

I tried to use `Int(value.sender)` but I have this error message:

```
sliderOutlet.setValue(seconds, animated: true)
```

> Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(Int, animated: Bool)'

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider!

@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    seconds = Int(sender.value)
    timeScreen.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
} 

@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(CountdownViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    sliderOutlet.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    stop()
    timeScreen.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    sliderOutlet.setValue(seconds, animated: true)
}

func stop()
{
    timer.invalidate()
    sliderOutlet.isHidden = false
}
```

I expected when I tapped on pauseButton, sliderOutlet will show current seconds' position.

Comment: When I tapped on pauseButton sliderOutlet show last position that I used
Here is my GitHub link
[link](https://github.com/Adakhan/StopWatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setValue(_:animated:)` method expects a `Float`, not an `Int`.

```
sliderOutlet.setValue(Float(seconds), animated: true)
```

Make sure the value of `seconds` is between the minimum and maximum values you have set for the slider which default to `0.0` and `1.0` respectively.